# Facebook Page Access Token list post all comments but not showing the unknown user name and id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-comments

I have created and Reviewed one of my Facebook Business app, when I am requesting for page token and try to list all comments of a post, I am getting maximum commenter user id and name, but whos are not using my app those people name and id are not showing.[image]

Comment: could be related? https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/835915183559820/

Comment: Thanks, Matteo, I am not getting the user name or id he/she does not use our app once